# How to prevent flickering of QDockWidgets when re-docking in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qdockwidget

I'm developing an application using Qt, where I have two QDockWidgets.

I have set these widgets to only dock on the left side of the main window, one on the left top and one on the left bottom, and I have set them to return to their original position automatically when they are dragged out and then released.
When I drag out one of the QDockWidgets, the remaining QDockWidgets automatically resize to fill the entire left side. However, when I release the dragged QDockWidget, causing it to return to its original position, a flicker occurs.

And I discovered that the returning QDockWidget first overlaps with the other QDockWidgets, and then the other QDockWidgets resize and reposition themselves. That's the cause of the flickering.

What I want to achieve is for the other QDockWidgets to immediately resize and reposition themselves when a QDockWidget is re-docked, in order to prevent this flickering.

How can I achieve this?
I've tried using an eventFilter to detect the `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease` event and immediately adjust the layout of the QDockWidgets when this event occurs, but this hasn't solved the problem.

What else should I try?
Or should I try more on an eventFilter to immediately adjust the layout?

Comment: I can't provide an answer, but I know for a fact that the QMainWindow API, no matter its extensibility (and due to how it's achieved), has known limitations both in usage and implementation, not to mention how each style actually achieves it. That's one of the reasons for which many attempted to work around it (eg. people at KDAB) with various levels of success. The main issue is related to the complex way of how placeholder geometries change and dock widget layout/reparenting happens, and how that is eventually achieved through the underlying platform integration, including event management.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.